# should I store financial log related information on a different database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, database-performance

I, we are developping an application since many years,
we have ~130 tables whose represent ~2.5Go of data reparted in 20 millions of "rows"~.

Until now whe have always stored all the datas in the same database, but I'm wondering if whe have done well, and if I shouldn't start to store new data on a different database (if possible).

- on one hand, using a single database permits to easily cross the data with complexe query
- on the other hand, I wonder if I'm not awakening the whole core system whose whould be more crash proof/performant with less data.

what do you think? wich one is best?

(I'm wondering because from now, I'll have to store every and single financial operation that pass within our app. (an ESB) . It woul be a good start to not store them on the core database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacity of your database depends on how big your DB server is.  Splitting the data into two databases on the same server won't improve performance and will make coding more difficult.

I had a single SQL Server database with 1.2TB of data, billions of rows

Comment: Your answer is good to read (I know the mysql can do much, but it's always alarming to massively add stress to a database).
I'm concerned not about only the raw capacity. For example the more intensive write operation of such type of log would be not great for the global QOS.

Comment: Your original post didn't say anything about how much data you add and how often.   If your app has a high write rate, but the users reading the data don't need up to the minute data, then a split database solution could be good. There are lots of software systems that have a "reporting database" that is used for queries and a real-time DB that gets new data.  You'd need a process to regularly regenerate the reporting database  from the live one.

Comment: My bad for the lack of information :'(
About the splitting with asynch. regeneration of data, it's an interresting scheme, it make me think about an asynch. replication from the "core" database to the "financial reporting" so I would be able to have all the nescessary data into the "financial" one but without the stress into the "core"